# SQL to get sequence of phone numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table called PhoneNumbers with columns Phone and Range as below

[image]

here in the phone column i have a phone numbers and in range column i have a range of values i need the phone numbers to be included.For the first phone number 9125678463 I need to include the phone numbers till the range 9125678465 ie (9125678463,9125678464,9125678465).Similarly for other phone numbers too.here is the sample destination table should look like

[image]

How can i write the sql to get this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello! Can you please post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just split the original number in 2 parts so that you have the prefix and rest, then either create a numbers table or dynamic tally table and join those together

Comment: @JamesZ that's pretty much what my answer does - glad i am not the only one who is thinking this way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution which goes a classic way BUT: it does not need recursions and it does not need any loops! And it works even if your range has length of 3 or 5, or whatever...

first i create a table with numbers (from 1 to 1 million in this example - you can adopt this in TOP () clause):

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_numbers ON dbo.Numbers(n)
;
```

if you have that table it's pretty simple:

```
;WITH phonenumbers
AS
(
SELECT  phone,
        [range],
        CAST(RIGHT(phone,LEN([range])) AS INT) AS number_to_increase,
        CAST(LEFT(phone,LEN(phone)-LEN([range])) + REPLICATE('0',LEN([range])) AS BIGINT) AS base_number
FROM    PhoneNumbers
)

SELECT  p.base_number + num.n
FROM    phonenumbers p
        INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers num ON num.n BETWEEN p.number_to_increase AND p.[range]
```

You don't have to use a CTE like here  - it's just to see a bit clearer what the idea behind this approach is. Maybe this suits for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE like this:

```
;WITH CTE (PhoneNumbers, [Range], i) AS (
    SELECT CAST(Phone AS bigint), [Range], CAST(1 AS bigint)
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(PhoneNumbers + 1 AS bigint), [Range], i + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE (PhoneNumbers + 1) % 10000 <= [Range] 
)
SELECT PhoneNumbers
FROM CTE
ORDER BY PhoneNumbers
```

Comment: This works but using a recursive cte like this is very inefficient as the processing is done row by row. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example of using a tally table. In my system I have that set of ctes as a view so I never have to write it again.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PhoneNumbers') is not null
    drop table #PhoneNumbers;

create table #PhoneNumbers
(
    Phone char(10)
    , Range smallint
) 

insert #PhoneNumbers
    select 9135678463, 8465 union all
    select 3279275678, 5679 union all
    select 6372938103, 8105;

WITH
E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)

select *
from #PhoneNumbers p
join cteTally t on t.N >= RIGHT(Phone, 4) and t.N <= Range
order by p.Phone
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach:

```
--Creating dummy table
select '9999991234' phone, '1237' rang into #tbl
union
select '9999995689', '5692'

SELECT [phone] low
        ,(CAST(9999995689/10000 AS bigINT) * 10000  + [Rang]) high
 into #tbl1
 FROM #tbl

--Creating 'numbrs' to have numbers between 0 & 9999 i.e. max range

select (rn-1)rn
into #numbrs
from 
(select row_number() over (partition by null order by A.object_id) rn from sys.objects A 
cross join sys.objects B)A 
where rn between 0 and 9999

select (low + rn)phn from #numbrs cross join #tbl1
where (low + rn) between low and high
```